# jQuery UI Layout resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I'm trying to use jQuery UI Layout to make two splitting panes like this: [image: this]

It works great, but the panes are not resizable and that's what i'm trying to acomplish. I can't find any documentation about it; I know it's possible because in http://layout.jquery-dev.com/ there are examples about it, but I just don't get it right!, if you guys could help I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!, apparently I had the two needed libraries but I had them in the wrong order as
jquery-ui-latest.js should be before jquery.layout-latest.js

That and establishing this properties:

$('#container-layout').layout({ east: {
   resizable: true,
   resizeWhileDragging:   true,
   slidable:              true
   }});

should do the trick!